# how to dynamically reload part of document

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, foreach

For a filemanagement, i use ajax to send the data to php file.
All data (reading files from directories) are outputted via `foreach`.

Like:

```
foreach($files as $file ) {
...
    echo....filename, size, delete etc....
```

To appear the changes immediately after the ajax call, i reload parts of the html in my `success` like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),              
    cache: false,

    contentType: false,
    processData: false,             

    success: function(data) {

    $('.myStorage').load(document.URL +  ' .calculateStorage');
    $('.myFiles').load(document.URL +  ' .table-responsive');
    $('.breadcrumb').load(document.URL +  ' form.crumbform');
```

So i use these `load()` -s for making the changes immediately visible for the user.

The div`myFiles` is part of the `foreach` loop which outputs the files.

But i think this is not the correct way to do it because doing it this way,
the complete foreach loop has to start again. But i am not sure how to handle with this so that changes after submit are immediately visible for the user. Is there another and better way to do it like this? And if so: how does it look like?

Comment: try having a look at fetch method and async and await for your problem

Comment: Well typically you would make a call, get some data, and then update the dom with that data  using  jquery `.html()` or something. I'm not familiar with php but in the client should look something like `getData() ` -> `$('.myStorage').html(someFormattedDataIwannaShow)`

Comment: you could cut this down to the ajax call with NO load calls. Simply have a php array with three keys: storage, files and breadcrumbs. Then echo json_encode($arry); And in your ajax success, simply loop through that data and create the HTML. This will decrease the time the visitor has to wait to see the updated file list.